# Multiple Facebook Like buttons (different activities) on one page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My one web page uses Ajax to display information about multiple activities.

I'd like to have one Like button per activity. This would mean multiple Like buttons on the page, one per activity. Can this be done?

Can the Like button's url include #!state1 ?

Eg, a web page is located at www.example.com/index.html

It has multiple FB Like buttons on it, one for url www.example.com/index.html#!activity1
another for www.example.com/index.html#!activity2

Will the two Like buttons work independently?

Comment: use share button instead! http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Share

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have multiple like buttons on a single page, but each like button must be linked to a separate page.

Eg: if you have products, each listing could have a like button next to it, but that like button would link to the product details page.

If you really wanted to, create phantom pages on your site with some [meta tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph). Then on your index.html, use like buttons that link to those pages.

To ensure no one ever gets to your phantom page, include the tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.example.com/index.html/">
```

That way, if someone clicks on the link that comes up on a facebook wall, they'll be redirected to the correct page.

Comment: Say you have a site linked to a facebook page, and you also have blog posts on the site. If you set up likes on individual blog posts, how can you manage their relationship to the single facebook page? Thanks

Comment: The problem with this is it doesn't give Facebook enough time to scrape the opengraph tags. I've set mine to 5 seconds, but it looks a bit odd as a user. How about restricting access to those phantom pages to the Facebook.com domain only... so they can scrap it, but the user can view it?